# Cloud Berry Linux Backup to AWS bucket

Tags: linux, cloudberry

We are trying to backup Linux to AWS, but notice there is no image backup but only files backup.
If it is a file system backup how do we restore and recover the system during a disaster recovery?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can try Veeam Agent for Linux.

The link is right here https://www.veeam.com/linux-cloud-server-backup-agent.html

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, currently, we do not have the Image-Based Backup for Linux. However, we have this feature on our roadmap.
As for disaster recovery, restoring the files can still be considered as a part of disaster recovery process.